# Decision boundary in ROC analysis

Tags: r

I am new to machine learning, and I found very good LASSO regression package called SIAMCAT.

A publication which used this package 'Potential of fecal microbiota for early-stage detection of colorectal cancer (http://europepmc.org/article/MED/25432777)' described very well so that I could easily approach to the complex machine learning method. However, there is one thing i could not understand their method, so that i politely ask for help.

the question i have is especially value of decision boundary. the authors said their decision boundary was 0.275 (fig 1A, 2A). However i have no idea where the value came from.

If the author can answer this question, i do want to ask where the value came from
(the certain 0.275 value)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The decision boundary is based on the model predictions. In `SIAMCAT`, you can access the model predictions using the `pred_matrix` accessor:

```
# load packages
library("tidyverse")
library("SIAMCAT")

# extract the mean predictions as data.frame
pred <- enframe(rowMeans(pred_matrix(siamcat_example)),
                name='Sample_ID', value='prediction')
# get the metadata information for the same dataset also as data.frame
meta.data <- as_tibble(meta.crc.zeller, rownames = 'Sample_ID')
# join the two data.frames together
df.plot <- full_join(pred, meta.data)
df.plot %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Group, y=prediction, fill=Group)) + 
    geom_boxplot()
```

If you now chose a random cutoff for the predictions, you can call everything above this cutoff positive and everything below it negative. This way, you will get a false positive rate and a true positive rate for the prediction cutoff:

```
cutoff <- 0.55
df.plot %>% 
  mutate(positive=prediction > cutoff) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(rate=sum(positive)/n())
```

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
Group  rate
<fct> <dbl>
1 CRC   0.585
2 CTR   0.148
```

Here, the false positive rate would be 0.148 and the true positive rate would be 0.585.

For the calculation of the AUROC, you basically go through every possible prediction cutoff or decision boundary and then you record the true positive rate and the false positive rate at this point. These two vectors are then plotted against each other and you get the ROC-curve.

In the case of the paper you mentioned (Zeller et al.), the authors chose a specific false positive rate at which to evaluate their model. So they checked which decision boundary would produce the desired false positive rate.

This information is stored in the roc object within the evaluation data of the SIAMCAT object:

```
# get the roc curve out of the siamcat object
roc.all <- eval_data(siamcat_example)$roc

# the roc object contains all decision boundaries and the resulting 
# sensitivity/specificities
# if we are interested in a false positive rate of 10%, this means
# we have to find the decision boundary corresponding to a specificity of 90%
# (specifity=1-fpr)
idx <- which(roc.all$specificities > 0.90)[1]
boundary <- roc.all$thresholds[idx]

# generate a similar plot as figure 2a in zeller et al.

df.plot %>% 
  # sort the samples by predictions and turn them into a factor to preserve
  # the order
  arrange(prediction) %>% 
  mutate(Sample_ID=factor(Sample_ID, levels=Sample_ID)) %>% 
  # then, generate the relative rank
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(rel_rank=seq_len(n())) %>% 
  mutate(rel_rank=rel_rank/n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  # additionally, check if the samples are above or below the decision boundary
  mutate(predicted_positive=prediction > boundary) %>% 
  # turn the group variable into a factor as well
  mutate(Group=factor(Group, levels = c('CTR', 'CRC'))) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x=rel_rank, y=prediction, col=predicted_positive)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = boundary) +
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(~Group, scales = 'free', space = 'free') + 
    xlab('Relative rank within the dataset') + 
    ylab('Model prediciton') + 
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```